# Joint cumulative distribution

Tags: random-variable, joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I'm studying joint distributions of two random variables, $X$ and $Y$. [Ross's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9353065607) (Chapter 6) defines the joint CDF as $F(a, b) = \mathbb P(X \le a, Y \le b)$ and the PDF as $f(a,b) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a \partial b} F(a,b)$.

I encountered an apparent contradiction. Consider the PDF $f(a,b) = 2 \exp(-x-2y)$ with $a\ge 0, b\ge 0$, and the corresponding CDF $F(a,b) = \exp(-x - 2y)$. Given the definition of $F$ in terms of probability, I would expect:

$$ a' > a \quad  \wedge \quad b' > b \quad \Rightarrow \quad  F(a', b') > F(a, b) $$

$F$ equals the probability that $X$ and $Y$ fall in the south-west quadrant as seen from $(a,b)$. Since the south-west quadrant of $(a', b')$ is a superset of the former, the probability should be higher and $F(a', b') > F(a, b) $. However, the CDF derived by integrating the PDF is monotonically decreasing in both $a$ an $b$, i.e. $ F(a', b') < F(a, b) $. Queue sad contradiction noises.

What am I missing?

**What I tried:**

Calculating probabilities of square areas over $F$ seems to give correct results:

$$ \mathbb P(a_1 \le X \le a_2, b_1 \le Y \le b_2) = F(a_1, b_1) + F(a_2, b_2) - F(a_1, b_2) - F(a_2, b_1) $$

It's just that the absolute values of $F(a,b)$ don't make much sense to me.

I also considered that I got something about the CDF wrong, but differentiating twice (wrt $a$ and $b$) introduces two $-1$ chain-rule factors, which cancel each other out. So the exponential terms in $f$ and $F$ will necessarily have the same sign, making both decrease monotonically with its arguments.

Comment: Your formula for the joint CDF is incorrect. You have computed the antiderivative of the pdf; what you need to compute is the _integral_ of the joint pdf which works out to be $(1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-2y})$.

Comment: I understand your point. Could you elaborate a bit how to go from the PDF to the CDF please? In this case your CDF is obvious in hindsight, due to independence. If possible, create an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Now that you have hindsight, explain how you found the CDF of $X$ or of $Y$ (other than "I looked up the result in my book or found it on the Internet") and repeat the process in the two dimensional case. If you don't understand how to find the CDF from the pdf in the one-dimensional case, read Chapter 5 of Ross again.

Comment: I understood the 1d case, my problem was with the n-d integration. I did not see how I could find the correct integration constants $c_{da}=2 \exp(-2b)$ and $c_{db}=1 - \exp(-a)$. I realize now that I get the correct result if I switch to a definite integral: $\int_0^{a'} f(a, b) da$ produces the correct integration constants and the correct CDF. Thanks for your help!